# Importing express$Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I am trying to create a local CommonJS module in Node containing utility functions for Express requests, and am unable to get a Flow type assigned to the req object. I have code like the following (trivialised for this example):

```
import type { $Request } from 'express';
const getRequestUrl = (req: $Request) => req.originalUrl;
module.exports = { getRequestUrl };
```

however when I hover the mouse over `req` above (in MS Code with the official Flow extension v1.0.1), it shows up as type `any` instead of `express$Request`.
If I type the `req` param as `http$IncomingMessage` (which doesn't need an import statement) `req` gets that type and I would get an error saying `originalUrl` is not present on that class' type.
I have "express_v4.16.x.js" installed in ./flow-typed/npm/

How should I be importing the `Request` type so that it gets used by Flow?

Comment: Maybe `import typeof { request } from 'express'`?

Comment: I tried this with a different LSP integration (not MS Code), and it works correctly for me with Flow v0.9.2 and the same type definition file from Flow Typed. Have you tried restarting Flow with `flow stop && flow`?

Comment: @JesseHallett I had tried restarting it, as well as going back to an earlier version, but was still seeing the error. I forgot about it for a while and worked on some other stuff, and while I wasn't looking, it seems to have fixed itself. I don't know how or why.